# What is the origin of the phrase "the eleventh hour"

Tags: etymology

Someone happened to use the phrase "the 59th minute of the eleventh hour" just now on IRC (#lisp on Freenode). I remarked that that should be "the twelfth hour". This then started me wondering where that apparently nonsensical phrase came from. It means at the last minute, of course, but in what sense is the eleventh hour the last minute? A quick google finds, for example http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eleventh_hour, but that doesn't really explain anything. The Biblical usage seems to mean "late in the day" (apparently 5 pm or so), not "at the last minute". Or is it just that the meaning of the phrase has changed slightly over time?

Comment: Here's Matthew Mead in [*The Good of Early Obedience*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22God+calls+not+till+the+eleventh+hour%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (1683): *If God calls not till the eleventh hour, he that comes in at the eleventh hour comes in good time; but he that is called at the first or third hour, may come **too late if he puts it off till the eleventh***.

Comment: @FF I'm not totally convinced about the relevance to linguistics, but the sentiment is marvellous.

Comment: Note that the Roman time system referred to twelve 'hours' from sunrise to sunset (and twelve hours of the night from sunset to sunrise). So *the eleventh hour* was by definition the period just before the end (of the day).

Answer (score 3):

Its origin is biblical and refers to the parable of the labourers in the vineyard (Matthew XX)

The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/60427?redirectedFrom=eleventh+hour#eid5640857) gives some indication of the etymology of the modern expression from as early as 971AD.

> **eleventh hour**: the latest possible time, in allusion to the parable of the labourers ( Matt. xx.); also eleventh-hour used attrib. or as adj.
>
> 971   Blickl. Hom. 93   Eall eorþe bið mid þeostrum oforþeaht æt þa endlyftan tid þæs dæges.

Comment: Interesting that this part of scripture is the appointed Gospel reading for Mass today.

Comment: Would you mind adding > quote marks to show what's quoted, please? And copy italics and suchlike accurately? (And the very last two words probably shouldn't be there)

Comment: @AndrewLeach What a coincidence. I should have also mentioned in view of the saturation coverage we have been getting on the First World War, that there was always irony in the fact that it ended on the eleventh hour of the eleventh day of the eleventh month of 1918. And it is at that time that we still commemorate the two-minutes silence every year.

Comment: I’ve done a quick and dirty edit to add quote marks, though I think the fact that basically the entire entry is copy-pasted from the OED here means that it’s definitely going past anything that can be labelled ‘fair use’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet By all means I will delete it if you prefer, but plenty of others copy paste from the OED all the time.

Comment: I would go through and get rid of most of the quotations, if I were you, leaving behind just a few chosen ones for illustration. That, to me, is fair use where simply copying everything is more likely to be taken as plagiarism.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, that link in my question references that, but it doesn't really explain current usage, or if that is the derivation, how this transformation came to be.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I have now deleted a number of the OED examples as some contributors were suggesting that a wholesale copy/paste was getting close to plagiarism. But I think you now have a useful port of call in the OED to help you develop an understanding of the etymology of this expression.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am now embarked on a review of all my postings over the last six years. And I shall reduce all OED quotations to a minimum of cut & paste, but with leaving a link to the on-line dictionary - which is a subscription service. I also intend to ask SE to redact all the OED material left in edits. We have to play fair with OED, I agree.